Python take data from two different dataframes, create a new dataframe and structure the data as collected from the other two
I'm very new to python and struck in an issue solving.
# First Dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Adam','Ashley','Adam','Don',],
    'items': ['Apple','Banana','Cherry','Date'],
    'Quantity': [10,15,20,25]
})

# second dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Adam','Ashley','Adam','Sunny'],
    'items': ['Apple','Banana','Scale','Pickle'],
    'Quantity': [11,10,15,20]
})

The above two dataframes have some similar values and some non-similar values.
I want to combine these two and prepare a dataframe - that has:

loops thorough both dataframes and collect the similar values for each name in one dataframe. Eg: Adam has two entries.

then loop through and see what is the issue- for eg. item not matching or quantity not matching and fill a new column "reason" with it. For the leftovers, I just need to add not available in df1/df2

I want to keep a blank line after each loop (1) iteration ,ie, after each name passes.



# Result
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Adam', 'Adam', None, 'Ashley', None, 'Don',None, None],
    'items': ['Apple', 'Cherry', None, 'Banana', None, 'Date', None, None],
    'Quantity': [10, 15, None, 20, None, 25, None, None],
    'name_2': ['Adam', 'Adam', None, 'Ashley', None, None, None, 'Sunny'],
    'items_2': ['Apple', 'Scale', None, 'Banana', None, None, None, 'Pickle'],
    'Quantity_2': [11, 10, None, 15, None, None, None, 20],
    'Reason' : ['Quantity mismatch', 'Item mismatch', None, 'Quantity mismatch', None, 'Does not exist in df2', None, 'does not exist in df1']
})


I greatly appreciate any help in this. Thank you in advance!
I accumulated these lines from multiple sources and of course, it doesn't work and shows various errors.
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for item in df1["name"]:
    idx = df2[df2["name"].eq(item)].min()
    idx2 = df1[df1["name"].eq(item)].min()

    new_df = new_df.append(df1[idx2])
    new_df = new_df.append(df2[idx])

    for i in idx():
        if df2["name"][i] in df1["name"]:
            if df2["item"][i] in df1[item]:
                new_df["Reason"][i] = "Quantity Mismatch"
            else:
                new_df["Reason"][i] = "Item Mismatch"
        else:
            new_df["Reason"][i] = "Does not exist in df1"



Could you please give me a better explanation about where those None values come from? I guess it is related to the third point, but it is really not clear to me.

@AME I'm really sorry for the confusion. None comes each time the loop for "name" ends. In the above example, Adam is selected and searched in both dataframes and then other steps are applied. Once this loop ends and it moves to the next "name", a blank line is added in the dataframe - that's the None values you see. So it's the last time of the loop.

I'm a bit concerned about generalizing this if the order doesn't match, if it's not always exactly ordered, how would you know which Adam to match in df_1 to the respective Adam in df_2?

@CeliusStingher Yes, that is actually something that I missed. You can say the primary key is the name column in both the dataframes. What if we make a unique list of "names" and then run the loop on that list and take values from the dataframes. Do you think that would work? Thank you for the valuable input.

My quick thought on this is that you would end up with a cartesian product as a result that would compare name repetitions within the same df

@CeliusStingher Understood, I can see that outcome as well. Would it be solved if we just loop in one unique name list. Then just add df2's leftover names from (uni_list2 - uni_list1) after looping in uni_list1 as they would be by default = "missing in df1".

@CeliusStingher But can you sample something that even provides duplicate values? I'm not able to successfully loop the two dataframes in the way I want. Any links/function/documentation if you might be aware of, would help a lot as well.

It's definitely not the cleanest code of my life, but maybe it's helpful, so I share it:
import pandas as pd


# First Dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Adam', 'Ashley', 'Adam', 'Don',],
    'items': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Date'],
    'Quantity': [10, 15, 20, 25]
})

# second dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Adam', 'Ashley', 'Adam', 'Sunny'],
    'items': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Scale', 'Pickle'],
    'Quantity': [11, 10, 15, 20]
})


def create_result(
    df1: pd.DataFrame,
    df2: pd.DataFrame,
    df2_columns: list
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[*df1.columns, *df2_columns, "Reason"])
    df1 = df1.reset_index()
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['name'])
    prev_name = None
    for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
        if prev_name != None and prev_name != row['name']:
            new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = pd.Series(dtype='float64')
        prev_name = row['name'] 
        rwsn = df2.loc[df2['name'] == row['name']]
        if rwsn.empty:
            new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = [*row.values[1:], None, None, None, "Name not found in the second dataframe."]
        else:
            rwsi = rwsn.loc[rwsn['items'] == row['items']]
            if rwsi.empty:
                # Here comes the problem because of the unclear identification, which value should I put into the items_2 column?
                new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = [*row.values[1:], rwsn['name'][0], None, None, "Item mismatch."]  
            elif row['Quantity'] != rwsi['Quantity'].values[0]:
                new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = [*row.values[1:], *rwsi.values.tolist()[0], "Quantity Mismatch."]
            else:
                pass # What should happen if they are identical?
    return new_df

print(create_result(
    df1=df1,
    df2=df2,
    df2_columns=['name_2', 'items_2', 'Quantity_2']
))

Take into consideration that this code will only take the values from the first table (like a left join), which means that the row for Sunny from the given example will not be visible. Although I am not sure if it is really useful to display it.
With the constraints you gave, I am not sure if it is possible to create general solution for this problem, as it was mentioned by @Celius Stingher.
You must change the structure of the data to clearly identify the records you want to compare. My solution also assumes that the columns are kind of strict and follow the naming convention that you presented, but I can imagine that it can be a problem if the columns change.

Thank you, AME! This is really helpful. I'll try to solve the above issues and see if they can be solved. Thank you so much!

For clarification purposes - "# Here comes the problem because of the unclear identification, which value should I put into the items_2 column?" = Here you would put both the rows in df1 and df2 (if items are same then against each other, else just like "missing in the dataframe" type in the next row.
As for the identical all 3 columns, there won't be as they are removed in a previous step.
